# как освободить ячейку памяти из динамического двумерного массива.Ну например здесь столбец который делиться на 3 не должна выделяться память

Tags: c++

mas = new int* [n];

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{

    mas[i] = new int[m];

}

for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {

        if (i % 3 == 0&& i!=0)
        {
            //delete [j]m[&i];
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Это не возможно для массива, без передвигания значений, или пересоздания массива.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Невозможно освободить одну "ячейку памяти" массива.

В вашем случае ("рваный" двумерный массив с *построчным* хранением) вам придется перестраивать каждую строку массива. Т.е. выделять память под строку уменьшенного размера, копировать все данные из исходной строки в новую память (пропуская ненужные ячейки), удалять исходную строку и на ее место прицеплять новую.